# Remove duplicates from linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void removeDuplicates(struct Node *start){

    unordered_set<int> seen;

    struct Node *curr = start;
    struct Node *prev = NULL;

    while(curr != NULL){

        if(seen.find(curr->data) != seen.end()){
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete(curr);
        }
        else{
            seen.insert(curr->data);
            prev = curr;
        }

        curr = prev->next;

    }
}
```

New to c++, can anyone explain this condition:

```
if(seen.find(curr->data) != seen.end())
```

Why should we only compare with the end() of the set, shouldn't we just check if we can already find the element in the set?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`std::unordered_set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find)? That check is precisely that, it checks if the element is already in the set

Comment: I assume this is for an exercise in pointers and/or linked lists, otherwise you would be using [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (or rather [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as it should always be the "default" container) and could have used [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: An alternative is to use [the `count` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count).

Comment: C++20 will have a [contains()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) method, fwiw. Have to do it manually until then.

Comment: Yep that was just for practice - thanks for all the alternatives!

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't we just check if we can already find the element in the set?

That's exactly what that code does. [`std::unordered_set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) returns an *iterator* to the element if it is found, or the end iterator otherwise.

If the data isn't in the set, the else branch of the `if` statement is executed, otherwise if it *is* in the set, the true branch.

Answer (score 0):

`seen.find(curr->data)` returns an iterator to what it finds.

If it doesn't find what is requested, it returns an iterator past the last element in the list. This is called `seen.end()`.

So the `if` is checking, that what is found, is what is requested. (it is not the end of the set)